# Ten Numbers for 10 Words

Tags: wordplay

**Ten words, 10 numbers.**

Can you:

- Match each number to the word it belongs with?
- Show the reason they are matches?
- Tell me a **word** matches with the number **FOUR**?

| WORDS | NUMBERS |
| --- | --- |
| SUIT | ELEVEN |
| SEER | FIFTY-FIVE |
| DEED | FIVE-HUNDRED FIFTY |
| DINE | FIVE-HUNDRED ONE |
| DOLE | NINETY |
| RASH | ONE-HUNDRED ONE |
| REAP | ONE-THOUSAND ONE-HUNDRED |
| ROOM | SIX |
| BOAR | SIX-HUNDRED |
| BEAM | TWO-THOUSAND |

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is how to match them

> Convert the number to Roman numerals. Then the characters should fit into the middle of (at least) one of the existing words to form a new word.

Here are the pairings

> SUIT + 2000 = SUIT + MM = SU**MM**IT.
>  SEER + 11 = SEER + XI = SE**XI**ER.
>  DEED + 55 = DEED + LV = DE**LV**ED.
>  DINE + 6 = DINE + VI = DI**VI**NE.
>  DOLE + 101 = DOLE + CI = DO**CI**LE.
>  RASH + 501 = RASH + DI = RA**DI**SH.
>  REAP + 600 = REAP +DC = RE**DC**AP.
>  ROOM + 1001 = ROOM + MC = RO**MC**OM.
>  BOAR + 90 = BOAR + XC = BO**XC**AR.
>  BEAM + 550 = BEAM + DL = BE**DL**AM.

A word that goes with FOUR

> SHOO -> SHOO + IV = SH**IV**OO

Comment: Beat me while I was typing it up ;)

The best choice for a pairing of FOUR that I could find is OLES (multiple olé?)

Comment: Ditto +1 - don't forget the third question! (In addition to mattshin's suggestion above, there's also a sandwich chain that would fit...!)

Comment: Thanks both, forgot about the last bit

Comment: I knew this wasn't too hard, but that was lightning fast!  The word I had in mind was indeed 'OLES' @mattshin  (but hex's answer is great too)

Nice work everyone!

Comment: If we're not limited to four-letter words, I found a trivial example of a more common word that might go well with 4. And if there's any leeway in the placement, another nice one can be found in the archives ;-)